# In the police station, why crash a car through the bulletproof glass?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

Couldn't the T-800 just punch through the glass, go through, and then assume attacking?

In the second movie, this does not stop the T-1000, even though a different model; it just punches through, turns into liquid and then resumes its mission. This was so unrealistic in the movie to where it could have just punched through instead of spending more time, going back to the car, and driving it into the police station.

Answer (score 1):

## The Terminator can afford to damage a car.

When the T-800 Terminator crashed a police car into a concrete wall, it damaged the mechanical components of its right wrist so severely that it could not use its right hand.  Lacking the quick-healing ability of the T-1000, the T-800 needed to take time to repair its hand before it could continue with its mission.

Later in the movie, the Terminator broke into the secure area of the police station using a disposable tool (a car) rather than one of its mission-critical hands.  The car failed to break the booth's glass, destroying the desk instead and popping the glass out of the frame.  Terminators are strong and durable compared to humans but weak and fragile compared to cars.  The Terminator would have wasted time and effort, endangering its mission, if it had tried to break the glass with its hand.